# I am trying to nest a map into a filter in RxJava2, so I can remove all objects that don't have the correct platform. But can't build it

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

```
override fun getVideoGamesRepository(platformName: String) {
    gameRepo = VideoGameRepositoryImpl()
    compositeDisposable.add(gameRepo.returnVideoGames()
        .filter { gameModel -> gameModel.gamesResults.map {  } }
        .subscribe())
}
```

Here is the method I have for filtering the data from the api. I will include a snippet of the data only for what is relevant.

I am trying to compare the value of the platform name in the database with the platform name I have entered in the previous activity. But the .map is underlined red at .map inside the filter.

```
{
"count": 363773,
"next": "https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page=3",
"previous": "https://api.rawg.io/api/games",
"results": [
    {
        "id": 28,
        "slug": "red-dead-redemption-2",
        "name": "Red Dead Redemption 2",
        "released": "2018-10-26",
        "tba": false,
        "background_image": "https://media.rawg.io/media/games/511/5118aff5091cb3efec399c808f8c598f.jpg",
        "rating": 4.54,
        "rating_top": 5,
        "ratings": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "title": "exceptional",
                "count": 1466,
                "percent": 70.28
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "title": "recommended",
                "count": 409,
                "percent": 19.61
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "meh",
                "count": 143,
                "percent": 6.86
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "skip",
                "count": 68,
                "percent": 3.26
            }
        ],
        "ratings_count": 2056,
        "reviews_text_count": 25,
        "added": 6296,
        "added_by_status": {
            "yet": 284,
            "owned": 3522,
            "beaten": 912,
            "toplay": 951,
            "dropped": 161,
            "playing": 466
        },
        "metacritic": null,
        "playtime": 22,
        "suggestions_count": 630,
        "user_game": null,
        "reviews_count": 2086,
        "saturated_color": "0f0f0f",
        "dominant_color": "0f0f0f",
        "platforms": [
            {
                "platform": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "PC",
                    "slug": "pc",
                    "image": null,
                    "year_end": null,
                    "year_start": null,
                    "games_count": 203916,
                    "image_background": "https://media.rawg.io/media/games/8e0/8e032ac4faf1136e7d708bb3ac61af23.jpg"
                },
                "released_at": "2018-10-26",
                "requirements_en": null,
                "requirements_ru": null
            },
            {
                "platform": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Xbox One",
                    "slug": "xbox-one",
                    "image": null,
                    "year_end": null,
                    "year_start": null,
                    "games_count": 3085,
                    "image_background": "https://media.rawg.io/media/games/c24/c24ec439abf4a2e92f3429dfa83f7f94.jpg"
                },
                "released_at": "2018-10-26",
                "requirements_en": null,
                "requirements_ru": null
            },
            {
                "platform": {
                    "id": 18,
                    "name": "PlayStation 4",
                    "slug": "playstation4",
                    "image": null,
                    "year_end": null,
                    "year_start": null,
                    "games_count": 4504,
                    "image_background": "https://media.rawg.io/media/games/4be/4be6a6ad0364751a96229c56bf69be59.jpg"
                },
                "released_at": "2018-10-26",
                "requirements_en": null,
                "requirements_ru": null
            }
        ],
```

Comment: We can help you better If you also could share your gameModel class

Comment: The model class is so long and full of clutter actually. It's just a model class to match against this JSON. Only the results in the JSON I chamged to GameResults, because Results is being used elsewhere in the project.

Comment: What is the code in your `gamesResults.map {  }` block?

Comment: What is the class definition of `gamesModel`? You'll have to dig into the structure and test via [`any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/any.html) for example.

Comment: There's nothing inside .map yet, as it keeps giving me an error when I do.

Answer (score 0):

[`filter`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html) method takes [`predicate`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/functions/Predicate.html) as a parameter. So you have to define a condition that returns true or false for your filter.

According to your model following code should return game results which contains your desired platform.

```
compositeDisposable.add(gameRepo.returnVideoGames()
  .map { gameModel ->
    gameModel.gamesResults.filter { gameResult -> gameResult.platforms.any { platform -> platform.name == platformName } }
  }
  .subscribe())
```

Also it seems you're storing the whole response object in your database. But I think this is unnecessary and not quite practical. Instead you could store the game result objects. Thus allowing you to reduce number of operations to achieve the same result. For example:

```
compositeDisposable.add(gameRepo.returnVideoGames()
  .filter { gameResult -> gameResult.platforms.any { platform -> platform.name == platformName } }
  .subscribe())
```

Comment: Well I want to check it against the platform name, if it doesn't match the platform name anywhere, I want to remove the whole object from being passed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot and all I needed to do was query the api call differently. 
So sorry, guys.